# How to fix Vue error `[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I still get this error

`[Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:`

even after making my `data` property a function to return a copy of my global state:

```
new Vue({
    'el': '#app',
    'data': function getState() { return _.cloneDeep(state); },
    'router': router,
    'template': '<Welcome />',
    'components': { Welcome }
});
```

What more does Vue want from me?

Comment: getState() should return array not object. 
'data': {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }

Comment: It's a little unusual to define a data function like that, but it looks OK. Are you sure that the error isn't coming from your Welcome component?

Comment: Just do `'data': _.cloneDeep(state)`. Only single component's need to return functions for their data argument.

Comment: My best guess is that `state` itself is not an object, because if it's not, rather than throw an error `_.cloneDeep` will just return undefined, rather than an object, thus resulting in your warning.  But you've really not provided us sufficient context, for instance, you've given no indication whatsoever of where `state` comes from.

Comment: Try this first `'data': function() {return state},` - also can you post how state is defined?

Comment: Thanks all, I see the problem was in my state. I wasn't exporting it as default. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

State had to be exported like

```
export default 
{
```

and not like

```
export const state =
{
```